# Working With Fragments: `Error inflating class fragment`

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, listview, android-fragments

I'm practicing with Fragments, and created a tester to get familiar with the process.

My goal is to create a simple app that has a ListView made up of 10 strings. The ListView is contained by a fragment within the MainActivity.

However, I have run into an error...

```
   FATAL EXCEPTION: main
   Process: com.example.frank.listview_test, PID: 5819
   java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.frank.listview_test/com.example.frank.listview_test.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #14: Binary XML file line #14: Error inflating class fragment
       at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3253)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3349)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1100(ActivityThread.java:221)
       at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1794)
       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:158)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7224)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120)
    Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #14: Binary XML file line #14: Error inflating class fragment
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:551)
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:429)
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:380)
       at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:284)
       at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:140)
       at com.example.frank.listview_test.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:17)
       at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6876)
       at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1135)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3206)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3349) 
       at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1100(ActivityThread.java:221) 
       at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1794) 
       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:158) 
       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7224) 
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230) 
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120) 
    Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #14: Error inflating class fragment
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:794)
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:716)
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:847)
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:810)
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:527)
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:429) 
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:380) 
       at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:284) 
       at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:140) 
       at com.example.frank.listview_test.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:17) 
       at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6876) 
       at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1135) 
       at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3206) 
       at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3349) 
       at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1100(ActivityThread.java:221) 
       at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1794) 
       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:158) 
       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7224) 
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230) 
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120) 
    Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.ListView.setAdapter(android.widget.ListAdapter)' on a null object reference
       at com.example.frank.listview_test.MainActivity$TestListFragment.onCreateView(MainActivity.java:37)
       at android.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:2281)
       at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:954)
       at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1141)
       at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.addFragment(FragmentManager.java:1245)
       at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.onCreateView(FragmentManager.java:2218)
       at android.app.FragmentController.onCreateView(FragmentController.java:98)
       at android.app.Activity.onCreateView(Activity.java:6070)
       at android.support.v4.app.BaseFragmentActivityHoneycomb.onCreateView(BaseFragmentActivityHoneycomb.java:36)
       at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onCreateView(FragmentActivity.java:75)
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:766)
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:716) 
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:847) 
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:810) 
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:527) 
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:429) 
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:380) 
       at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:284) 
       at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:140) 
       at com.example.frank.listview_test.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:17) 
       at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6876) 
       at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1135) 
       at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3206) 
       at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3349) 
       at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1100(ActivityThread.java:221) 
       at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1794) 
       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:158) 
       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7224) 
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230) 
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120)
```

Here is my relevant code...

**activity_main.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:background="#FFFFFF"
    android:gravity="center"
    tools:context="com.example.frank.listview_test.MainActivity">

    <fragment android:name="com.example.frank.listview_test.MainActivity$TestListFragment"
        android:id="@+id/list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</FrameLayout>
```

**list_fragment.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/listFragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/testListView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:gravity="center" />

</FrameLayout>
```

**list_item.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="70dp"
    android:textSize="50sp"
    android:textColor="#000000"
    android:layout_gravity="center"/>
```

**MainActivity.java:**

```
package com.example.frank.listview_test;

import android.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    public static class TestListFragment extends Fragment {

        private String[] myStringArray = new String[20];
        private ListView listView;

        private void setArray() {
            for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
                this.myStringArray[i] = "hello";
            }
        }

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            setArray();

            ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(),R.layout.list_item , myStringArray);
            listView = (ListView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.testListView);
            listView.setAdapter(adapter);

            // Inflate the layout for this fragment
            return inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_fragment, container, false);
        }
    }
}
```

Is there any bit of this code that stands out as wrong that could be causing this error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your fragment code `onCreateView()` should first inflate the `list_fragment` layout that contains the `ListView`. Then you should be calling `findViewById()` on the inflated layout and not on the activity since the fragment layout is not yet a part of the activity view hierarchy.

For example:

```
// Inflate the layout for this fragment
View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_fragment, container, false);
listView = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.testListView);
listView.setAdapter(adapter);

return view;
```

Comment: awesome. that worked. so, my next question is, if you don't mind, when would you ever call `findViewById()` on activity from within the Fragment class? Is there ever case where you would use `getActivity().findViewById` from within the fragment class?

Comment: Almost never. From design point of view, the fragment should be independent of its hosting activity and don't care about activity's specific details such as other views in hierarchy. For the fragment to find its own views it's better to restrict to the fragment's own view subtree that you create in `onCreateView()` and can later access e.g. with `getView()`.

Answer (score -1):

try this:

```
View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_fragment, container, false);
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(),R.layout.list_item , myStringArray);
            listView = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.testListView);
            listView.setAdapter(adapter);
return view;
```

Answer (score -1):

This error might be occur when we are going to load fragments on activity at runtime.
So, the code pattern are like,

There are Three files:
1. MainActivity.java
2. WelcomeFragment.java
3. LoginFragment.java

MainActivity.java

```
FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
    FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();

    WelcomeFragment f1 = new WelcomeFragment();
    fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.fragmentContainer, f1);
    fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);
    fragmentTransaction.commit();
```

WelcomeFragment.java

```
public class WelcomeFragment extends Fragment {
    Button btnLogin;

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_fragment_welcome, container, false);
        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
        btnLogin = view.findViewById(R.id.btnLogin);
        btnLogin.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
                LoginFragment f2 = new LoginFragment();
                FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
                fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.fragmentContainer, f2);
                fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);
                fragmentTransaction.commit();
            }
        });
    }
}
```