# Android Studio trouble getting Json from an API

Tags: java, android, json, http

I'm new to android studio and java.  I'm trying to get some Json from an API.  It crashes every time I try to build the URL and pass the URL to my method getResponseFromHttpURL.  Any guidance would be appreciated!

```
public class NetworkUtils {

   private static final String movieApiUrl = "http://api.themoviedb.org/3/discover/movie?sort_by=popularity.desc&api_key=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX";

   public static URL buildURL(){
        Uri builtUri = Uri.parse(movieApiUrl).buildUpon()
                .build();

       URL url = null;

       try{
            url = new URL(movieApiUrl);
        }catch(MalformedURLException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

         return url;
    }



    public static String getResponseFromHttpUrl(URL url) throws IOException{

        HttpURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        try{
            InputStream in = urlConnection.getInputStream();

            Scanner scanner = new Scanner(in);
            scanner.useDelimiter("\\A");

            boolean hasInput = scanner.hasNext();
            if(hasInput){
                return scanner.next();
            }else{
                return null;
            }
        }finally{
            urlConnection.disconnect();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please provide the error message you are getting :). Furthermore you could take a look at [Retrofit](https://github.com/square/retrofit)

Comment: I'm getting an "Error inflating class fragment"

Answer (score 0):

If the request is not in a background thread/task, it will most likely stop it's regular activity to make the request and whenever completed, not able to continue where it was left on. Try placing the connection in an `AsyncTask` so it's regular activity maintains operational.

> https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html
>
> https://developer.android.com/training/volley/simple.html

Edit: Aparently the error is `fragments-error-inflating-class`, so it has nothing to do with this answer. Will leave this be as it can help someone in need

Comment: Either I'm using AsyncTask wrong or its still crashing with the same error "Error inflating class fragment"

    public class FetchMovieTask extends AsyncTask<URL, Void, String>{
        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(URL...url){
            try{
                String jsonMovieData1 = NetworkUtils.getResponseFromHttpUrl(url[0]);
                return jsonMovieData1;
            }catch (Exception e){
                e.printStackTrace();
                return null;
            }
        }

Comment: That error has nothing to do with the HTTP Request, please update your post with the error and check this link if it may help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39031669/working-with-fragments-error-inflating-class-fragment